# Tufte-book with standard natbib style author-year citations

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, tufte

I would like to use the standard `natbib` way of citing papers using the `tufte-book` class. This means that I want citations in the text such as (Pilegaard et al., 2014) and an alphabetic bibliography list at the end of the book.

I have looked at the questions/answers on the net about tufte-latex and bibliographies, but so far I have not succeeded with anything that works as wanted. What I have now is:

```
\documentclass[titlepage, a4paper, twoside, justified]{tufte-book}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\wpYoffset -6.5cm

\bibliographystyle{plain}

\title{Impacts of climate\\change on\\terrestrial ecosystem functioning --\\an   overview}

\author{Beier, C., et al.}

\begin{document}
.
.
.
\bibliography{climaite_overview} 
.
.
.
\end{document}
```

This gives me numbered citations in the text like this [13, 17] and a nice alphabetically listed bibliography at the end.

Comment: I should add, that I already use the form \citep{Pilegaard2014} in the text.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`tufte-book` modifies the `\cite`-command heavily, you can turn this behavior off, using the `nobib`-option:

```
\documentclass[titlepage, a4paper, twoside, justified, nobib]{tufte-book}
```

In order to get `natbib` working, you have to call and configure it manually:

```
\usepackage{natbib}
\setcitestyle{authoryear}
```

You also have to use `plainnat` instead of `plain`:

```
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
```

Now you can use `\citep` to get citations in parens.

[image]

```
\documentclass[titlepage, a4paper, twoside, justified, nobib]{tufte-book}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

\usepackage{natbib}           % call natbib
\setcitestyle{authoryear}     % set citation style to authoryear
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}  % use the plainnat instead of plain


% -------------------------------
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Pilegaard2014,
   title     = "Differentiating moss from higher plants is critical in studying the carbon cycle of the boreal biome",
   publisher = "Nature Publishing Group",
   author    = "Kim Pilegaard and Wenping Yuan and Shuguang Liu and Wenjie Dong and Shunlin Liang and Shuqing Zhao and Jingming Chen and Wenfang Xu and Xianglan Li and Alan Barr and Black, {T. Andrew} and Wende Yan and Goulden, {Mike L.} and Liisa Kulmala and Anders Lindroth and Margolis, {Hank A.} and Yojiro Matsuura and Eddy Moors and {van der Molen}, Michiel and Takeshi Ohta and Andrej Varlagin and Timo Vesala",
   year      = "2014",
   doi       = "10.1038/ncomms5270",
   volume    = "5",
   journal   = "Nature Communications",
   issn      = "2041-1723",
}
\end{filecontents}
% -------------------------------

\title{Impacts of climate\\change on\\terrestrial ecosystem functioning --\\an   overview}

\author{Beier, C., et al.}

\begin{document}
.
.
.
Bla bla \citep{Pilegaard2014} bla.
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. However, if I add more references, I get an error:                                                 ! Argument of \@citex has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.57 ...citet{beier2012} and \citet{mikkelsen2008}

Comment: It is hard to figure out what went wrong by guessing, so could you please post the issue with `\citet` as a new question with a MWE detailing the problem? (You can use the given example and add references and text until it breaks.)

Comment: It turned out that the reason for the error was some Danish language characters (æ, ø, å) in the bib file. When I replaced them with pure LaTeX characters, the error disappeared.